# How to use a function in an iteration method?

Tags: functions, matrix

I am calculating a matrix 'HTotal', which depends on a variable in the end. I want to write it down as a function so that I can evaluate it for different values of the variable.

```
HTotal = ArrayFlatten[{{HAA, HAB}, {HBA, HBB}}]
```

Now if I write

```
 htotal[λ_] := HTotal
```

it doesn't work an I should copy the answer of 'HTotal' and paste it in front of

```
 "htotal[λ_] :="
```

in order for it to work. but this is very time consuming as I have a different 'HTotal' in each iteration. Does anybody know a faster way to describe a function?

Example:

```
      H1 = {{λ, 2 λ}, {1 + λ, 3 - λ}};
      H2 = {{1 + λ, 2 - λ}, {λ, 3 λ}};
       HTotal = ArrayFlatten[{{H1, H2}, {H2, H1}}]
```

This doesn't work and it doesn't evaluate the function:

```
       htotal[λ_] := HTotal
       htotal[1]
      {{λ, 2 λ, 1 + λ, 
       2 - λ}, {1 + λ, 3 - λ, λ, 
      3 λ}, {1 + λ, 2 - λ, λ, 
      2 λ}, {λ, 3 λ, 1 + λ, 
      3 - λ}}
```

But this works:

```
  htotal[λ_] := {{λ, 2 λ, 1 + λ, 
  2 - λ}, {1 + λ, 3 - λ, λ, 
  3 λ}, {1 + λ, 2 - λ, λ, 
  2 λ}, {λ, 3 λ, 1 + λ, 
  3 - λ}}

    htotal[1]
    {{1, 2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 3}, {2, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 3, 2, 2}}
```

Comment: You will have to provide much more detail, preferably by offering a simplified example.

Comment: @Alan I have added an example to the question, Thank you

Comment: This is a classic instance where you should use `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`.  You could alternatively apply `Evaluate` to `Htotal` in your function definition.

Comment: @Alan Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers 
Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

To see what the problem is, look at the definition of your function.  (I'll just use `Lambda` as the variable, for ease of reading.)

```
htotal[Lambda_] := HTotal
Definition@htotal01  (*result: htotal01[Lambda_] := HTotal *)
```

Note that `Lambda` does not appear in the definition.  So when you evaluate it, you end up simply substituting `HTotal` for your expression.  You can see this as follows:

```
Trace@htotal[1]
```

Suppose we use `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`:

```
htotal02[Lambda_] = HTotal
```

Looking at the definition, you see it involves your function parameter.

```
Definition@htotal02
```

So this function will do parameter replacement:

```
Trace@htotal02[1]
```

Alternatively, you could you `SetDelayed` but apply `Evaluate` to the right-hand side.  And btw, don't forget that you can evaluate `HTotal` for a given lambda just by using `ReplaceAll`, so you may not even need to write a helper function.